# gpgme-1.18 fails to compile

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to compile gpgme-1.18 from source according to the instructions at https://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/postlfs/gpgme.html

The compile fails, with the below error:

```
Making all in python
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/lang/python'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/lang/python'
set -e ; for PYTHON in /usr/bin/python3.10; do \
  CPP="gcc -E" \
  CFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-format-y2k -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-format-zero-length -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-sizeof-pointer-div" \
  srcdir="." \
  top_builddir="../.." \
    $PYTHON setup.py build --verbose --build-base="$(basename "${PYTHON}")-gpg" ; \
done
running build
Using gpgme.h from ../../src/gpgme.h
Please use --libdir=LIBDIR option or set PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
Or set PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Could not find gpg-error-config.  Please install the libgpg-error development package.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:758: all-local] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/lang/python'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:475: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/lang/python'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:460: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/lang'
make: *** [Makefile:538: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Computers lie!  Earlier, in the configure process, the script was able to see gpg-error-config.

```
checking for gpg-error-config... /usr/bin/gpg-error-config
checking for gpgrt-config... /usr/bin/gpgrt-config
configure: Use gpgrt-config with /usr/lib as gpg-error-config
checking for GPG Error - version >= 1.36... yes (1.46)
configure: Use gpgrt-config as libassuan-config
```

I can verify it's path location:

```
brad_b82 [ ~ ]$ which gpg-error-config
/usr/bin/gpg-error-config
brad_b82 [ ~ ]$
```

gpg-error-config is a symlink:

```
brad_b82 [ ~ ]$ file /usr/bin/gpg-error-config 
/usr/bin/gpg-error-config: symbolic link to gpgrt-config
brad_b82 [ ~ ]$
```

When I run gpg-error-config, I get the following:

```
brad_b82 [ ~ ]$ gpg-error-config
Please use --libdir=LIBDIR option or set PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
Or set PKG_CONFIG_PATH
brad_b82 [ ~ ]$
```

I'm at a loss at where to look to troubleshoot my issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

## # #

EDIT #1, REGARDING BRUNSON

I did verify the location of libgpg-error.so
I also copied the same libs to /usr/share/libgpg-error/ which the documentation tells me is the default location.

```
Making all in python
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2/lang/python'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2/lang/python'
ln -sf "../../../../src/data.h" .
ln -sf "../../conf/config.h" .
ln -sf "../../../../lang/python/src" gpg
touch copystamp
set -e ; for PYTHON in /usr/bin/python3.10; do \
  CPP="gcc -E" \
  CFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-format-y2k -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-format-zero-length -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-sizeof-pointer-div" \
  srcdir="../../../../lang/python" \
  top_builddir="../.." \
    $PYTHON setup.py build --verbose --build-base="$(basename "${PYTHON}")-gpg" ; \
done
running build
Using gpgme.h from ../../src/gpgme.h
Please use --libdir=LIBDIR option or set PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
Or set PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Could not find gpg-error-config.  Please install the libgpg-error development package.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:758: all-local] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2/lang/python'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:475: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2/lang/python'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:460: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2/lang'
make: *** [Makefile:538: all-recursive] Error 1
brad_b82 [ ~/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2 ]$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep gpg
libgpg-error.so
libgpg-error.so.0
libgpg-error.so.0.33.1
brad_b82 [ ~/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2 ]$ ls /usr/share/libgpg-error/
errorref.txt  libgpg-error.so  libgpg-error.so.0  libgpg-error.so.0.33.1
brad_b82 [ ~/gpgme-1.18.0/build1/build2 ]$
```

New things I want to point out.  The "cl" and "cpp" portions of gpgme bindings seem to compile fine.  It's not until it tries to compile the python bindings that it chokes.

I also tried to read every line of output during the python part, and I noticed something odd... ***Using gpgme.h from ../../src/gpgme.h***

there would be no such path, as the directory I was in was ~/gpgme-1.18.0 which expanded is simply /home/brad_b82/gpgme-1.18.0

With me not having enough knowledge to fix the issue, I decided to simply try:

```
cd ~
rm -Rf gpgme-1.18.0
tar -xvf gpgme-1.18.0.tar.bz2
cd gpgme-1.18.0
mkdir build1
cd build1
mkdir build2
cd build2
../../configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --disable-gpg-test
```

My thought process was that now, ../../src/gpgme.h actually exists.  Still fails though. Yes, I did include the --libdir=/usr/lib just to try to cover bases, even though that exact same path appears in the configure script without adding it.

Comment: It's telling you exactly what to do: use --libdir or set PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR or set PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Unfortunately, I don't know what to set them to, but that should be the start of your investigation. You're using linuxfromscratch, did you install it into a non-standard directory?

Answer (score 0):

I need to answer this question and close it...

The linuxfromscratch devs has very recently released a patch to gpgme that solves the issues.

I'm not a programmer, but it does appear that I was at least on the right track when I was seeing the script try to pull from directories that don't exist.

Problem solved, case closed.